# Dual monitor broken in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, graphics, ati, multiple-monitors

I upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04 and now my dual monitor support seems broken.
When booting, I see the screen duplicated just fine on both my laptop as my external monitor; after logging in, however, the external monitor disables and cannot be enabled.

**Hardware:**

- Dell Studio XPS 1640 laptop
- GFX: Ati Mobility Radion HD4670
- Extenal monitor: Acer P193W

I get the following **error message** when applying screen settings:

> The selected configruiation for
>   displays could not be applied
>   requested virtual size does not fit
>   available size: requested=(3040,900),
>   minimum=(320,00), maximum=(1600,1600)

**`lshw` output:**

```
  *-display
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: ATI Technologies Inc
        vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        version: 00
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
        resources: irq:50 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:cfef0000-cfefffff memory:cfe00000-cfe1ffff
```

**Screenshots:**

[image: Screen settings]
[image: Error message after clicking apply]

Answer (score 1):

You're able to resolve that issue by removing .config/monitors.xml.
Steps are:
 1.rm ~/.config/monitors.xml in terminal
 2.log out and log in
 3.call monitors utility and setup your 2 monitor configuration again.

Comment: This has not solved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me ( Ubuntu 11.10 ), but I used the proprietary after the upgrade to oneiric

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it with ATI Catalyst Control Center (Administraive). It is available from System -> Preferences

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the maximum desktop size is 1600x1600, which is probably big enough to cover the laptop's display (in either landscape or portrait mode) but not the external monitor.

You will probably have to create an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file to set a larger maximum size.  A minimal `xorg.conf` that should achieve this is:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Default Screen"
    Device          "Default Video Device"
    SubSection "Display"
        Virtual         3040 900
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

If you've already got an `xorg.conf` for some reason, try adding the `Virtual` option to the relevant location.

There shouldn't be much of a downside to setting the `Virtual` size larger than you need: modern versions of the X server only use as much memory as needed for the current display layout rather than reserving the maximum.

Comment: Sadly, this has not solved my problem. In fact, when adding the `virtual` parameter, both my laptop and external monitor *do* active, but are stuck at a max resolution of 1280x800 or so. I have removed the parameter and am now again stuck with only my laptop. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at your question again, it looks like you might be using the proprietary `fglrx` driver.  Perhaps try switching back to the standard drivers instead.  With my Evergreen series Radeon card, the standard drivers work fine with multiple monitors (I don't have an `xorg.conf`, and it defaults to a 8196x8192 as the maximum size).  The standard drivers perform a lot better with this card on 11.04 than they did with 10.10, so it might be worth trying them out again.